# Passing id through links in HTML

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

In an ASP.Net MVC project, I have a list of countries. Once user selects one country, I need to list its provinces.

I came up with this:

```
<a href="/Common/Province/Index/">"Provinces"</a>
```

How can I pass the countryId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that in the view that is used to display the list of countries uses a model that has a list of countries.

```
List<Country> AllCountries {get;set;}
```

and in the view you probably have a script that looks like this to load the list of countries

```
<ul>

            @foreach (var country in Model.AllCountries)
            {
                <li>
                    <span>@country.Name</span>
    <!-- <a href="/Common/Province/Index/">"Provinces"</a> remove this line-->
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Province", new { countryId = country.CountryId })">provinces</a>
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
```

and modify your action in the "Province" controller to take a parameter "countryId" like the code below

```
public ActionResult Index(int countryId)
        {
            //code
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Sam for trying to answer my question. I finally could find my answer : <a href="/Common/Province/Index/?countryId={{Country.Id}}">Provinces</a>

Answer (score 1):

First off, in your controller, you'd need a method that takes the country id and passes the provinces list as output. Then you can [run an AJAX method](http://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/) on the select change.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("ControlerMethodName", "ControllerName")',
            data: { parameterName: dataFromView},
            success: function (result) {
                doStuff(result);
            },
            error: function (req, status, error) {
                doOtherStuff(error);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I have the countryId in the view as it is already sent by the controller. I need to know how can I pass it using the href. I tried : <a href="/Common/Province/Index/ConutryId">"Provinces"</a>   but it did not work.

Comment: To list provinces of a country, I need to pass a countryId to the Index action in the province controller. But it is not the point! My question is how can I use the href and send a parameter value.

Comment: Thanks 9Deuce for trying to answer my question.This is the one that worked for me : <a href="/Common/Province/Index/?countryId={{Country.Id}}">Provinces</a>